# Wakeup Listener (MaxListenersExceededWarning) Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http2

I am getting the following warning in my node application:

```
(node:245) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 wakeup listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
    at _addListener (events.js:260:19)
    at Connection.addListener (events.js:277:10)
    at Connection.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:687:35)
    at Connection.once (events.js:306:8)
    at Connection._send (/mnt/app/node_modules/http2/lib/protocol/connection.js:356:10)
    at runCallback (timers.js:651:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:624:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:596:5)
```

I understand what is going on in terms of this event listener is being registered more than the default max of 10 listeners. I know I could just up this number, but I am not sure if this would be fixing the problem, or just covering it up.

This is in the http2 node_module, but I don't know what is invoking it.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "conciergeapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --trace-warnings ./bin/start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apn": "^2.1.3",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.15.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.8.6",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "nodemailer": "^2.7.2",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^4.0.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-beta9",
    "request": "^2.80.0",
    "socket.io": "^1.7.3",
    "socketio-jwt": "^4.5.0",
    "xoauth2": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm experiencing the same issue with the same call stack.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it never caused any major issues and the total listener count never went above 11 for me so I just let it go.